# Is there a more recursive way to do this?

Tags: python, django, recursion, django-templates

I have the following code:

```
{% if thing.parent.parent.parent.link %}
    <a href="/y/{{ thing.parent.parent.parent.link }}">{{ thing.parent.parent.parent.name }}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if thing.parent.parent.link %}
    <a href="/y/{{ thing.parent.parent.link }}">{{ thing.parent.parent.name }}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if thing.parent.link %}
    <a href="/y/{{ thing.parent.link }}">{{ thing.parent.name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

The key thing that changes in this non-recursive code, is simply adding a .parent to the link/link text.

I need to do this 20 times in total, as you can see, it's quite ugly to repeat and quite repetitive. Is there a more recursive and nicer way of doing it using django's template framework?

Answer (score 2):

Return a list in your context and then you can use an iterative approach:

```
{% for parent in parents  %}
    <a href="/y/{{ parent.link }}">{{ parent.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Since nothing special has to be done if it is a child (as you mentioned, the only difference is link and name), you can just convert the things' parents to a list. I cannot give an exact method to do this without knowing more about your data structures, but maybe this will give you an idea:

```
 parents = []

 for thing in things:
     node = thing
     while hasattr(node, 'parent'):
         parents.append(node.parent)
         node = node.parent
```